# Unable to see feature xml screens when I have created site map entry for acumatica screen and disabled acumatica feature

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am using some acumatica manufacturing screens in my customization feature and I have enabled my customized feature but disabled acumatica manufacturing feature, In this case I am not able to see screens. when I enabled acumatica manufacturing feature I can see this screens.

Is there any attribute or any thing I can use in feature xml so I can see this screens once i have enabled my customized feature.

Answer (score 0):

The system disables all pages by ScreenID prefix folder if the associated feature is not enabled. Move your custom pages into a new prefix folder, change the site map entries, and they will appear.

e.g.

from /Pages/AM to /Pages/AR